# animejs - move relative to current position

Tags: javascript, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to move the div relative to the current position in animejs

```
var myAnimation = anime({
   targets: ['.location'],
  translateY: "-300px",
  easing: 'linear',
   delay: function(el, index) {
    return index * 80;
  },
  duration: 500,
  loop: false
});
})
```

I tried

```
 translateY: "-=300px",
```

without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get your starting point via js and specific it with brackets. 
Like this:

```
property: [startpoint, endpoint]
```